# Emulating Geo Location in Chrome with moving

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, google-chrome, geolocation

My Question is based on Chrome's GeoLocation spoofer which allows me to swap my locations in order to test my nodejs app. The problem is it is designed to leave a 'trace' following the history of the movements. It's really annoying to type new coords in the Chrome console every time I have to move.

Could you point me a place/addon/piece of code where I can set up 10-20 coordinates in a circle(using loop) and force the emulation to follow those coordinates every few seconds. So I can finally simulate moving and continue developing the tracing function from the front-end point of view ?

My point is I need a real-like spoofer and Chrome gives us perfect one, but I gotta make the little guy moving.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution sir? I am in the some situation.

Comment: Really? Nothing for Windows and Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac available to you, there is a moving GPS simulator in Xcode. Download Xcode (free on the Mac App Store) and run the iOS Simulator. Open Safari in the Simulator. Then in the Simulator's Debug menu choose Location and then pick from one of three moving simulations. Alas they are all in the San Francisco Bay area. The Custom Location option only allows you to put in a single coordinate and not a series of them.

You could even ask a friend with a Mac to just open your web app in their iOS Simulator and leave it running while they do other stuff.

[image]